# ocaml when reading the book by Jason Hickey

Tags: ocaml

For the final rule, explicit annotation for higher-order functions, consider the following definition of a function apply.

```
# let apply g = g ~x:1 2 + 3;;  
val apply : (x:int -> int -> int) -> int = <fun>
```

I do not understand the above line and thus the following stuff:

Note that the compiler infers that the function `~g` has a labeled, not an optional argument. The syntax `g ~x:1` is the same, regardless of whether the label `x` is labeled or optional, but the two are not the same.

```
# apply (fun ?(x = 0) y -> x + y);; Characters 6-31:
apply (fun ?(x = 0) y -> x + y);; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This function should have type `x:int -> int -> int` but its first argument is labeled `~?x`

The compiler will always prefer to infer that an argument is labeled, not optional. If you want the other behavior, you can specify the type explicitly.

```
# let apply (g : ?x:int -> int -> int) = g ~x:1 2 + 3;; val apply : (?x:int -> int -> int) -> int = <fun>
# apply (fun ?(x = 0) y -> x + y);;
- : int = 6
```

Is there anyone able to help?

Comment: Did you look at Real World Ocaml, while it's not a gentle intro, it's very well written https://realworldocaml.org/

Comment: It is not clear what is the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `?` syntax instead.

```
let apply g = g ?x:(Some 1) 2 + 3
```

The other reasonable approach is to give `g` a type signature.

```
let apply (g : ?x:int -> int -> int) = ...
```

Comment: There is a typo: it should be g ?x:(Some 1) 2 + 3

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just started to learn ocaml. Basically, for the first line:
# let apply g = g !x:1 2 +3;;
I think it is defining a function 'apply' with parameter g. Then g is a function with two parameters. one is labeled: ~x:1. Then I get confused. Let alone the following discussions on optional parameters.